# wrap selected text in <span> on behalf of selection of drop down list

Tags: javascript, select, ckeditor

I have a drop down list out of editor area . I have to add `<span>` on selection of any of those list item around the selected text. I have made styles for this .But its not working.
Note: I am not using any plugin.

```
document.write( '<select id="markup" onchange="createEditor( this.value );">' );
            var markup = ['Person','Event','Place'];
            for ( var i = 0 ; i < markup.length ; i++ )
            {
                document.write(
                    '<option value="' + markup[i] + '">' +
                        markup[i] +
                    '</option>' );
            }
            document.write( '</select>' );
var editor;
                function createEditor( selected )
                {
                    if ( editor )
                    editor.destroy();
          /*        CKEDITOR.stylesSet.add( 'my_styles',
[
{ name : 'Span1', element : 'span', attributes : { 'itemprop' : 'prop' } },
{ name : 'Span2', element : 'span', attributes : { 'itemscope' : '' , 'itemtype' : 'type' } }
]);         */
                    editor = CKEDITOR.replace( 'editor1',
                        {
                        style : new CKEDITOR.style(
                        {
                            element : 'span',
                            attributes : {  'itemprop' :  'prop' },
                        }),
                        style1 : new CKEDITOR.style(
                        {
                            element : 'span',
                            attributes : { 'itemscope' : '' , 'itemtype' : 'type'  },
                        }),
                            on :
                          {
                                instanceReady : function()

                              {
                                   //  config.stylesSet = 'my_styles';
                                    var mark = document.getElementById( 'markup' );   
this.style.apply(editor.getSelection().getSelectedText());
                                //  this.style1.apply(editor.document);

                                }
                            }
                        } );
                }
                createEditor( '' );

            </script>
```

Please Help anybody in wrapping selected text in `<span>` on selection of list item of drop drop down list.